# Как сделать так, чтобы две программы пользовались отдельными сетевыми интерфейсами?

Tags: windows, сеть, vpn

В системе имеется два сетевых интерфейса и vpn соединение. Каждый из интерфейсов подключен к разным провайдерам. Есть две программы которые должны использовать определенный интерфейс (сетевой адаптер). Программа (а) должна использовать адаптер (а), а программа (б) должна использовать VPN-соединение через адаптер (б). Если более подробнее объяснять. Чтобы firefox использовал интерфейс (а), а торрент клиент качал исключительно через VPN который подключен через адаптер (б). По сути вопрос заключается в том, как все это работало отдельно.

Comment: Вообще-то по какому пути пойдёт трафик стандартно определяется только по адресу назначения.

Comment: Вот это посмотрите https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip

Comment: @Sergey r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip по описанию то что мне надо (на деле не пробовал). А с помощью него можно ли сделать так, чтобы определенная программа подключалась не только через интерфейс, но и через VPN который подключен через определенный интерфейс?

Comment: Наверное. VPN во-первых обычно сам создаёт интерфейс (виртуальный), во-вторых есть какой-то ip-адрес. Т.е. получается третий интерфейс в)

Comment: @Sergey Уважаемые, Сергей. Заранее извиняюсь за наглость. Не могли бы вы мне помочь с настройкой данного программного решений (forcebindip)? Желательно через какие либо сервисы общения в режиме реального времени. ВК может быть?

Comment: Нет. Я его сам не использовал никогда. Нечего добавить к тому, что написано на сайте.

Comment: Вопрос актуален.

Comment: Да чтож там не понятного?
Использование:  
ForceBindIP не имеет графического интерфейса. Вы должны использовать его как приложение командной строки. Для запуска программы 'app.exe' и привязки её к ip-адресу 1.2.3.4, Вы должны запустить ForceBindIP так: `ForceBindIP 1.2.3.4 c:\full\path\to\app.exe`

Сделайте копию ярлыка IE. В свойствах замените объект `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` на `ForceBindIP 1.2.3.4 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`, вместо `1.2.3.4` напишите адрес нужного интерфейса. Аналогично torrent, но с адресом VPN

Comment: @Sergey дело в том, что при подключенном VPN даже если я указываю IP другого адаптера, программа использует VPN (по всей видимости ForceBindIP присваивает IP программе, а потом через указанное IP выходит в сеть через VPN (не пинайте за тупое объяснение)). Хотелось бы чтобы определенная программа работала через VPN, а определенная программа работала через другой интерфейс обходя VPN

Comment: У вас должно быть два маршрута по умолчанию. Вероятно при подключении VPN этот самый VPN уничтожает старый маршрут, прописывает свой собственный. Надо как-то сделать так, чтобы оставались оба. Тогда должно работать, если конечно windows не какой-нибудь допотопный вроде XP

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/25/source-ip-address-selection-on-a-multi-homed-windows-computer.aspx здесь описывается как происходит выбор исходящего адреса и исходящего интерфейса. На Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 и новее с помощью forcebindip как раз должен получиться нужный вариант. Но там ничего не сказано как сделать несколько маршрутов (шлюзов) по умолчанию. Есть только упоминание `default gateway associated with Nic` Вот об этом теперь и надо спрашивать

Comment: @Sergey благодарю. Не стал заморачиватся с этим. Нашел IP-адреса и прописал маршруты.